# canvas.itemconfig results in infinite event-loop

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

I try to draw a little 3x3 board with a marker on each cell.
This marker should only show up, when the cell is touched with the mouse.
This works once, twice, sometimes 3 three times - but then the event-loop 'fires' infinitely (always the same event)...

```
import tkinter as tk

cellsize = 50

class Board(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Canvas.__init__(self)

        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(3):
                ulx, uly = column*cellsize, row*cellsize
                lrx, lry = ulx+cellsize, uly+cellsize
                _cell = self.create_rectangle(ulx, uly, lrx, lry,
                                              fill='green')
                _right = self.create_rectangle(ulx+39, uly+20, lrx-1, lry-20,
                                              fill='red',
                                              state='hidden')
                self.tag_bind(_cell, '<Enter>', 
                              lambda e, r=_right: self.show_pos('on', r))
                self.tag_bind(_cell, '<Leave>', 
                              lambda e, r=_right: self.show_pos('off', r))

    def show_pos(self, onoff, right):

        print('{} {}'.format(onoff, right))
        if onoff == 'on':
            self.itemconfig(right, state='normal')
        elif onoff == 'off':
            self.itemconfig(right, state='hidden')

root = tk.Tk()
Board().grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Perhaps this is sticked to the self.itemconfigure statement, because doing other things (e.g. updating a status line) work as expected.

Is there a solution for this?

Thx in advance

Marvin

Addition:
To be more precise: It seems to stick with the 'state=..."
Changing the itemconfig to 'fill=...' in 'show_pos' works as expected.
So the title should be
'canvas.itemconfig(state='...' results in infinite event-loop'

Comment: as "update" is beeing called after a state change (Tkinter.py, def _cnfmerge) your state change results in additional state changes which - running the mouse fast enough results in your loop. Try to achieve the binding with mouse position calculation instead of enter / leave and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mouse position approach you could use:

```
class BoardX(tk.Canvas):
    __cells=None
    __indicators=None
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self)

        self.__cells=[]
        self.__indicators=[]

        self.bind('<Motion>', self.show_pos)

        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(3):
                ulx, uly = column*cellsize, row*cellsize
                lrx, lry = ulx+cellsize, uly+cellsize
                self.__cells.append(self.create_rectangle(ulx, uly, lrx, lry,
                                              fill='green', tags="cell"))
                self.__indicators.append(self.create_rectangle(ulx+39, uly+20, lrx-1, lry-20,
                                              fill='red',
                                              state='hidden', tags="indicator"))
    def show_pos(self, event):
        """ Get closest widget or widget that we are above,
            tagged "cell" and indicate it
        """

        # the loop is needed for not to run into value errors
        halo=0
        widget = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y, halo=halo)

        # edit - avoid loop!
        if not widget[0] in self.find_withtag("cell"):
            return

        index = self.__cells.index(widget[0])

        for i in range(len(self.__indicators)):
            state='hidden'
            if i == index:
                state='normal'
            self.itemconfig(self.__indicators[i], state=state)
```

This does not fire leave events you bound to in your approach and should therefore solve your problem.

If you do not want to take this approach for whatever reason you could only bind to `enter` and hide every other indicator using the `find_withtag("indicator")`-Approach

**Edit**
Code sample is corrected to avoid the loop.

Comment: Thx for your answer.

Comment: <Sry Pressed Enter too soon>  Based on your previous short comment I played around with find_closest. I stored the cells and indicators in a dict with corresponding bbox-values as keys. The 'tag'-stuff didn't come in my mind. To be short: I was not very successful. But your solution - nonetheless much more elegant - does not work either. After pushing the mouse around sometimes, it stucks infinitely in the while..-loop. I decided to use a simpler solution and paint the indicators in background color and handle if the mouse 'enters' the indicator.